# Need to convert a generic to its interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have created an interface and classes as follows:

```
public interface IRecord
{
}
public class Person : IRecord
{
}
public class Company : IRecord
{
}
public class Contact : IRecord
{
}
public class Table<T> where T : IRecord
{
}
```

I also have a static class to manage the tables.  I'd like to be able to get a particular table based on a switch statement:

```
public class DataBase
{
    public static Table<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public static Table<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public static Table<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public static Table<IRecord> GetTable(eDataType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case eDataType.company:
                return Companies;
            case eDataType.contact:
                return Contacts;
            case eDataType.person:
                return Persons;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, the return lines all throw compile errors:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Table<Company>' to 'Table<IRecord>'
```

Can I modify my code to return the correct table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to handle this would be to add a non-generic base class. It can even be `abstract` if you want to ensure nobody can try and instantiate it.

```
public abstract class TableBase 
{
}
```

And then you can have:

```
public class Table<T> : TableBase where T : IRecord
{
}
```

And now this would work:

```
public static TableBase GetTable(eDataType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case eDataType.company:
            return Companies;
        case eDataType.contact:
            return Contacts;
        case eDataType.person:
            return Persons;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that, because a `Table<Company>` is not a `Table<IRecord>`, even though `Company` implements `IRecord`. That's because `Table<T>` is not [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd799517%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (classes can't be covariant anyway, only interfaces and delegates can).

To explain why, let's assume that your `Table<T>` class has an `Insert(T record)` method; if you were able to treat a `Table<Company>` as a `Table<IRecord>`, it would allow you to insert a `Person` or `Contact` in the table, which would obviously be incorrect.

Now, the question is, how are you going to use the returned table anyway? If you're only going to read it, you could define a covariant interface like this:

```
public interface ITable<out T> where T : IRecord
{
}
```

Then make `Table<T>` implement this interface, and change `GetTable` to return `ITable<IRecord>` instead of `Table<IRecord>`.

Note that the interface can only have `T` in an output position (i.e. it can't, for instance, have a method that takes a `T` as a parameter), or it won't be allowed to be covariant.